# yarn commands output killed: 9

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

When I try to `yarn install`, `yarn version`, `yarn upgrade` there is no messaging other than `killed: 9`

Are there any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Running Catalina 10.15.7, Node v15.13.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the machine seemed to resolve this issue.